# Encrypt Azure service bus using customer managed keys when data is already present

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have a compliance activity to encrypt my Azure Service Bus premium to encrypt using a customer-managed key. However, Microsoft documentation states that the namespace must be devoid of queues, topics, and data. My ASB has data, up and running. I cannot afford to downtime to delete queues, enable encryption, and then continue. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

If you check this **[Configure customer-managed keys for encrypting Azure Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/configure-customer-managed-key)** document then you will find that -

> Azure Service Bus Premium provides **encryption of data at rest** with Azure Storage Service Encryption. Service Bus Premium uses Azure Storage to store the data. All the data that's stored with Azure Storage is encrypted using Microsoft-managed keys.

And it also has a limitation as you mentioned int the question that **the encryption can only be enabled for new or empty namespaces**. If the namespace contains any queues or topics, then the encryption operation will fail. There is no other option.

So we have the two type of encryption as follows -

- **Encryption at Rest** -
  Azure ensures the disks used in persisting the messages are encrypted either with Microsoft Managed Keys (which is the default) or  [customers managed keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/configure-customer-managed-key)  to encrypt the disks.
- **Encryption in Transit** -
  This is basically protecting the medium which is used to transmit the data from point-to-point. A classic of this would be  [TLS/SSL encryption in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/encryption-overview#tlsssl-encryption-in-azure)  being used to encrypt the data transmitted.

For more information read the best practices in [Securing Azure Service Bus](https://azurehangout.com/securing-azure-service-bus/) and [Encrypt Azure Service Bus Data at REST using User Keys documents](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/encrypt-azure-service-bus-data-at-rest-using-user-keys).